# INSERT or UPDATE : importing data and managing update

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I face an insolvable issue (for me).

I have a client table

```
CREATE TABLE `client` (
  `cli_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `cli_active` SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cli_id`));
```

According that we have to import file with following informations :

```
cli_id   |  cli_active
-------------------------
1          |    0            
2          |    1         
1          |
```

Column cli_active can be empty and in this case I want to keep the value stored in the database.

```
insert into clients(cli_id , cli_active)
value
(1,0), (2,1), (1,default)
ON duplicate key update
cli_active = if(values(cli_active) = default(cli_active), cli_active, values(cli_active));
```

With this request I can't make the difference between "default" and "1" defined in insert.

How can I know if the insert value is "default type" and not the default value.

I hope I'm clear...

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you declare a value number which you will not use for `default`?

Comment: my workaround is to set a value not used (2) instead of default in the insert part and to test the value 2 in the update part in order to set cli_active = cli_active (for keeping the ddb value). But with this method, I have to execute an update to change value 2 in default value for all the lines newly inserted.